# Facebook Like button url?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

Is there an actual link that if clicked and someone is logged in will have them automatically like my fan page? I'm sick of FaceBook's terrible code and am looking for alternatives for a better "Like" button.  Suggestions are welcomed,  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing other than the Like button. Your only other option is to use a Like box.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

If you meant a Like Box, then there is nothing that will achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the facebook like button because it provides statistics for your site or blog, you can also create or use an app like reference your button.

[Facebook Like Button (Graph API v2.3)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button)

[Facebook Insights](https://www.facebook.com/insights/)

[image]